# Why is the webrtc blob address located on signalling server?

Tags: node.js, blob, webrtc, stun

I've used the easyrtc toolkit (http://easyrtc.com/) (written for nodejs) to setup a chatting system inside my office network. I did not do much to implement this setup and simply used the demos which were provided with the toolkit. The application is hosted on a VM inside the office, while the default ICE configuration of the toolkit mentions STUN and TURN servers located outside the office firewall.

The system is working fine, but I have a doubt. After initiating a webrtc video chat with my colleague sitting on another computer in the office network, I did a "Inspect Element" on his video. I was expecting the blob address to be at his IP address, as I believe that we've created a peer-to-peer connection between us. But the IP address turned out be the VM's IP address where the app is hosted. Why is this happening?

```
<video autoplay="" id="callerVideo" src="blob:http%3A//10.30.23.56/e09742eb-941a-456f-88dc-addfb013c8e9"></video>
```

Here 10.30.23.56 is the VM's address. While the video is coming from my colleague's webcam.

Answer (score 2):

The video tag is playing the video from a MediaStream Blob object that was created by the PeerConnection. This Blob object is represented via a URL string which is only an identifier, which in this case is constructed using the URL of the window + a unique identifier. See This [MediaStream API on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/WebRTC/MediaStream_API). You should not read into this blob ID as the source IP of the media. The source would be the other peer and its IP address would depend on whether the host IP, reflex IP (via STUN) or the TURN's IP was used. If you want to see the actual IP address and Port from where the video is streamed you can either inspect the SDP and the ICE Candidates that were generated and exchanged between the peers, or you can use Chrome's webrtc-internals (chrome://webrtc-internals) tool.